# Getting timeout error while calling NSE India get url using Feign Client as well as Rest Template in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate, spring-cloud-feign

This is the Url I want to call
GET https://www.nseindia.com/api/holiday-master?type=trading

It is working in postman and from browser as well, but when I am trying to call this api from my code in Kotlin it is throwing Read timed out.

These are the two implementations that I tried :

```
@FeignClient(value = "nse", url = "\${usage.url.nseUrl}")
interface NseProxy {

  @GetMapping(
    value = ["/api/holiday-master?type=trading"],
  )
  fun getHolidayMaster(): NseHolidayMasterResponse
}
```

and ,

```
RestTemplate().getForEntity("https://www.nseindia.com/api/holiday-master?type=trading", NseHolidayMasterResponse::class.java)
```

After reading that some basic headers are also required, I tried :

```
@FeignClient(value = "nse", url = "\${usage.url.nseUrl}")
interface NseProxy {

  @GetMapping(
    value = ["/api/holiday-master?type=trading"],
  )
  @Headers(
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36"
  )
  fun getHolidayMaster(): NseHolidayMasterResponse
}
```